Finding values of a and b such that there are 100 twin triangles with integer sides
We define two triangles as "twins" if they meet the following criteria:
Both triangles have integer side lengths $(a, b, c_1)$ and $(a, b, c_2)$ respectively.
The triangles share two common side lengths $a$ and $b$.
$c_1$ and $c_2$ are the only sides that differ between the two triangles.
Both triangles must have the same non-zero area.
Let's define the number of twins for given $a$ and $b$ (where $a \neq b$) as $P(a,b)$.
Are there any values of $a$ and $b$ such that $P(a,b) = 100$? If so, what is a non-computational approach to identifying such $a$ and $b$?
For any $a$ and $b$, what is $\max_{a,b} P(a,b)$?
In what cases is the area of a pair of twins rational or irrational?
Heron's formula provides the area of a triangle given its side lengths. Consider the graph of the area function $A(c)$ derived from Heron's formula, where $a$ and $b$ are fixed and $c$ varies:
$A(c) = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$, where $s = \frac{a+b+c}{2}$.
If we fix $a$ and $b$, we can plot Heron's formula as a function of c. To ask my question in a graphical way, we are particularly interested in cases where this graph intersects multiple integer vertical lines (representing integer values of $c$) at the same height (same area).

For a triangle with side lengths a, b, the area of the triangle is $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin\gamma$ where $\gamma$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$. If the area of two triangles with these two side lengths is equal, it follows that they then have the same angle sine, which restricts the possibilities to 2 at most (since once the angle is determined the 3rd side length can be calculated from the law of cosines). So $P(a,b)$ is always 0, 1 or 2

Plotting the Heron's area formula as a function of c yields a concave degree 4 polynomial. Since triangle sides are only positive, the maximum intersections with a horizontal line is 2. However, the same polynomial could have multiple twins. For example, for a = 24, b = 23 yields three twins: (c1 = 29, c2 = 37) with area of ~268, (23, 41) with area of ~235, and (19, 43) with area of ~204

I see what you’re saying, my mistake

Given $a$ and $b$ and an acute angle $0 < \gamma < \frac{\pi}{2}$ between them, the area of the triangle is given by $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin\gamma$ and by the law of cosines the third side is given by $c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\cos\gamma}$. There is exactly one triangle with the same area and side lengths given by choosing the obtuse angle $\pi - \gamma$ which gives the side length $c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + 2ab\cos\gamma}$. Therefore, our resulting side lengths are $c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 \pm 2ab\cos\gamma}$, which are bounded below by $|a-b|$ and above by $a+b$, and have a average square value of $a^2 + b^2$.
We can therefore reframe the problem as, once $a$ and $b$ are given, how many pairs of integers $(c,d)$ exist with $|a-b| < c < d < a+b$ and $c^2 + d^2 = 2(a^2 + b^2)$? This is a modified lattice circle problem; if there were no bounds, we could use the sum of squares function $r_2(2a^2 + 2b^2)/8$ to count this, which is usually a small number. More work can be done using this strategy but I wanted to show how this could be translated into something that theoretically can be calculated more explicity. This also gives $r_2(2a^2 + 2b^2)/8$ as an upper bound on $P(a,b)$ for any $a$, $b$.
Edit: example: the smallest value $n$ with $r_2(n)/8 \geq 100$ is $5^4\cdot13^4\cdot17\cdot29\cdot37 \approx 3.3\times10^{11}$ so any $a, b$ with $P(a,b) = 100$ has to have $a^2 + b^2$ at least that big.
